# Non-CrossTargeting GetTargetFrameworks target should not be used in cross targeting (outer) build only on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have a Solution that has a console project which is referring to one class library project. It's working as expected in Visual Studio 2017. But When I try to build the solution in Visual Studio 2019 it gives the below error in the console app project.

> Non-CrossTargeting GetTargetFrameworks target should not be used in
> cross targeting (outer) build

Class library csproj file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{E05F3549-01FC-4012-A2CA-5BF009608E80}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>FxRateCalculationLib</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FxRateCalculationLib</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Console app csproj file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{34A8C575-F374-4C50-8ADC-EC74A6423055}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApp1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ConsoleApp1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
```

I tried to change changing from

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

then it builds successfully. but When I run It starts giving runtime errors.

So I have a question why is it working in VS 2017, but not in 2019. and how to fix this issue with minimum and proper changes.

**Edit**: initially I thought that it was an old legacy project, so I add a new console application project using visual studio 2019. But same compilation error is mentioned above in the question.

**Edit2**: Complete error message

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Internal MSBuild error: Non-CrossTargeting GetTargetFrameworks
> target should not be used in cross targeting (outer)
> build ConsoleApp1

Comment: Could you give the full error?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I have updated the question, please check the Edit2 section.

Comment: `TargetFrameworks` is for multiple targetframeworks, a single TargetFramework, you need to use `TargetFramework`. `v4.7.2` is used in the <TargetFrameworkVersion> attribute, and `net472` is used in the <TargetFramework>/<TargetFrameworks> attribute. What is the specific message of the runtime error?